# "You can only post once every 20 minutes" validation does not work

Tags: support, asking-questions, meta, rate-limiting

The validation ***Posting a new question after 20 minutes*** is not working. You can compare the time this current question was posted with the time the previous question was posted.

One may compare these two questions.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226277/how-does-favorite-tags-edit-work-when-i-didt-add-any-favorite-tag

and

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226276/paging-goes-back-to-1st-page-when-changing-questions-per-page-option

The first question was asked **30 mins** ago and second one was asked **18 mins** ago. That makes the difference **12 mins** and not **20 mins**.

So is this a bug?

Comment: Yup ! You have asked 3 questions before 20 minutes. I don't know why it's not working. hold on bug

Comment: I wonder if the rules on meta are different, I can't find anything to suggest that but it is often the case

Comment: @RichardTingle . Why you can't? You can see my question posted time differences

Comment: As in I can't find anything to suggest that **the rules on meta** are different. Often rules are relaxed on meta whicj would explain this if true

Comment: Meta has no such limits as far as I know